# Oracle & java dynamic 'Order by' clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to build a dynamic sql query in java (shown below)

```
    sqlStr = "Select * " +
        "from " + tableName

    if(tableName!=null){
        if(tableName.equals("Table1"){
            sqlStr = sqlStr.concat("order by city desc");
        }else if(tableName.equals("Table2"){
            sqlStr = sqlStr.concat("order by country desc");
        }else if(tableName.equals("Table3"){
            sqlStr = sqlStr.concat("order by price desc");
        }
    }
```

Now what i would like to do is to add a final 'else' statement which would order the query based on whether the table contains a column named 'custID'. There will be several tables with that column so i want to sort the ones that have that column by custID. (Rather than having hundreds of additional if statements for each table that does have that column name.) Is this possible? i have seen people using the 'decode' function but i cant work out how to use it here.

Comment: You should adda space before your `order` or you will have a syntax problem. Plus it isn't a good idea to work with a table which you know nothing about, you problem is a more general design problem.

Comment: while composing dynamic query ,please use StringBuilder instead of using string ,"+" and concat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to get the table information.

You can use the `getTablexxx()` and `getColumnxx()` methods to get the table information.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(.....);
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
dbmd.getxxxx();
```

Note: you forgot space in your code before `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Hi yes i noticed the missing space.            Is it possible to use this in a single query? Or do i have to issue one query to find out the column names first then build the final query? I guess the other option is to use the metadata and sort the resultset rather than sort using SQL but that would be expensive.

Comment: I think you will have to fire atleast 2 queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with hardcoding things, a way to avoid multiple conditionals would be to store a list of all the tables that include `custID`.

```
private final static String tablesWithCustID = "/TableX/TableY/TableZ/";

...

if (tablesWithCustID.contains( tableName )) {
  sqlStr = sqlStr.concat("order by custID")
}
```

You could use a List instead of a simple delimited string if you like.

Perhaps better, you could store a map with table names as the key, and the sort string as the value.  Load it up once, then you don't need any conditional at all.

Comment: You might even be able to avoid hardcoding this by building it at application startup from database metadata. Enumerate all tables, and look through the columns in each to choose a sort key (eg "the custID column if it has one, else country if it has one, oh, but always price for Table3"), and store that.

Comment: Tom has a good point.  Best of both worlds is to build the lookup table using metadata once.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward way to do it is to read the column definitions from USER_TAB_COLUMNS or ALL_TAB_COLUMNS and check for the existence of a custID column. Without crazy PL/SQL tricks, you won't be able to solve this in SQL alone.

BTW, there is a " " missing between tableName and the order by clauses.

Comment: USER_TAB_COLUMNS is Oracle specific.  DatabaseMetaData is portable between RDBMS.

Comment: Agreed. Though Oracle and portable hardly go hand-in-hand.

Comment: Using user_tab_columns requires the use of pl/sql which im trying to avoid.

Comment: ziggy: No, you don't need PL/SQL to read USER_TAB_COLUMNS. You can read it like any other table or view with a simple SQL query.

Comment: `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` requires extra permissions from DBA.

Comment: @Ashsish: I don't think so. Why should a user not be allowed to read the definitions of his own tables?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you're looking for a solution that can do this in one query, i.e. without running a separate metadata query beforehand.

Unfortunately, this won't be possible. The *decode* function can do some dynamic things with column values, but not with column name. And you're looking for a solution dynamically derive the column name.

An alternative might be to just add `ORDER BY 1, 2`. This is an old syntax that means order by the first and than by the second column. It might be a good solution if the custID column is the first column. Otherwise it at least gives you some sorting.

Answer (score 1):

How about `ArrayList.contains()`?
You can create a list of tables which have that column, and just check for `tables.contains(tablename)` in the final if condition.